# How can i add 2 different user tables to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am developing a site on the wordpress platform that i want it to have 2 different user table in the admin area, one table for Internal people and one for reg users (external). is there a plugin out there that can do this?

i don't know if this is possible. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two user tables to differentiate between users. Wordpress has [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that allow you to categorise and give access to different user groups.

You can set up the default role in the general settings and display or  restrict content accordingly.

There are plenty of examples in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) of how to do this but if you prefer a plugin there are several, [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) is one of the more popular ones.